# looping not working javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

how can i loop imm(imacros) script with javascript

can you help me ?

```
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://test.com/" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL " + "\n"; 
macro +=  "wait seconds=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=ID:like-*" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "wait seconds=0.5" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=360" + "\n"; 
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
ret=iimSet("i",i);
ret=iimPlay(macro);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here...Can you be more specific?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We appreciate your code, but "It's not working" is a fairly unhelpful comment.  Could you provide any error messages or actual outcomes vs. expected outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

```
var macro;

    macro =  "CODE:";
    macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://test.com/" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL " + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "wait seconds=1" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=ID:like-*" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "wait seconds=0.5" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=360" + "\n"; 
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
    iimSet("i",i);
    ret=iimPlay(macro);
    }
```

Try now.

Edit: corrected the previous bug.

Comment: t's the same that I make,
I feel confused with looping function.

Comment: Try now. I've never seen ret=iimSet("i",i); to be used anywhere. So I corrected it.

Comment: same :( not loop, what have you can email me contact

Comment: Try now. After the first line there is no "\n" . That part comes in second line.